# how to avoid the overlapping of many overlay widget - flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, stack, overlay

0

in my case I have a bunch of questions and each question have a list to choose one of the existing answers displayed in overlay widget.

for my list i used an overlay.

the problem is if there is other overlay, they will hide each other same as stack order its child (the last child widget will be overlapping above the other children of stack) the

the result of my code looks like:

before click the first overlay to animate to the big size
[image]

after click the overlay widget

[image]

I cant use the entry.remove() cause I want the overlay stay shown but only the size will change to small size after user choose one of the displayed answers. (I'm using animatedContainer for that)

I'm looking for a way to make the selected widget overlay above the other overlay widgets
so any suggestions to solve this? or maybe the way of implementation is wrong ? and thanks

something like [this](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/22839194/131275765-9f1c037c-b4c5-4dfe-877f-14d5ee3f16e5.mp4) (the selected one will always shown at the top)
https://pub.dev/packages/indexed